# where is the executable bit in page table entry?

Tags: linux, operating-system, paging

[image]

this is a figure from Intel architecture manual.
in x86 32bit page table entry, where is the bit
which indicates if the page is executable or not?

if it's not here, how can a OS set memory permission for exec?
with something like mmap function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, a page is executable if it's readable, so they all executable. But, what you might thinking here is that, there are pages which has nonexec bit set. Well, that's a software hack, done from kernel. This technique was introduced to avoid stackoverflow based attack, by making a particular page (vm area) non-executable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. you said 'software hack', could you be a little bit more specific about this?  I'm curious how this can be managed without hardware support.  because OS can not interfere with application's instruction execution unless there is H/W interrupt. so, if an application is running his/her code in some exec-able page and the EIP jumps into a non-exec-able page, how can OS intercept this and make it stop at the right moment?

Comment: Well, you can find it http://pax.grsecurity.net/docs/pageexec.txt, this document explains everything.

Comment: thank you! the document gave me thorough understanding how NX can be implemented!